# Reverting MS Access version

Tags: ms-access

I use JMP stats software to open an Access database (Version 2108 32-bit) and keep getting the error **"ODBC Microsoft Access Driver Login Failed - The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access"**. Looking further into the error, it seems that the database is using the features (BigInt, etc..) which cause Access to upgrade to the version 16.7. I checked the version of the database (?Application.CurrentDB.Version) and it was 16.7.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to determine which table(s) is using the new features? I have 20+ tables in the database so it is very time consuming to go through each table.
2. How to properly revert the version back to 12.0? This is the known working version for my case.
3. How to prevent users from using the new features?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need to simply use an older version of the ODBC driver. The one you are using is looking for a newer version of Access. You can go to Control - Panel > 32-BIT DNS sources to check the ODBC driver version, and install and use an older ODBC driver if you need to. The ODBC driver is independent of JMP.

Comment: @DanielG: On the contrary: A *newer* version of the ODBC driver (which can handle bigint fields) would probably fix it. My guess would be to use the ACE driver instead of the JET driver.

Comment: @DanielG, the current driver version is 14.00.7010.1000. My guess is "14.00" is the version of Access? If so, wouldn't I need a newer version (which I can't find), like 16.00...?

Comment: @Heinzi, could you provide the link to the new drivers if possible? Engine 2016 is the latest I could find. Thank you!

Comment: @BQUNguy: Hmm... after doing a bit more research, I'm not so sure any more that there even *exists* an ACE driver supporting bigint fields. Anyway, on my machine (Office 2019 C2R consumer), odbcad32.exe shows that my Access driver has a version of 16.00.15225.20278. What does yours say? Be sure to check both the 64-bit version (C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe) and the 32-bit version (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe [sic]).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Use *DAO* to open the *TableDef* objects and read the data type of the fields. However, for only 20 tables, manual inspection is probably faster, indeed if you wish to modify those fields using BigInt.
2. After having made the necessary corrections, create a new (empty) database file and import the objects from the corrected database.
3. Educate the users.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I went through the table and couldn't find where BigInt was used. I think for now I would make a copy of the tables with the number fields set to not SmallInt and delete the original(backup).